# showing image in pdf puppeteer not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to generate a PDF using Puppeteer. But the images are not showing in the page .PDF file .

Both images from HTML and CSS are not showing. Am I missing something?

#### index.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
               
        <img src="logo_head.png" class="logo">
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
(async function() {
    try{
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'});
 
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        
        const content = await compile('index',data) 
 
        await page.setContent(content,{ waitUntil: "networkidle0" });
        await page.emulateMediaType('print');
        
        
        await page.pdf({
            path:'output2.pdf',
            displayHeaderFooter: true,
            
        })
 
        console.log("done creating pdf")
 
        await browser.close()
 
        process.exit()
 
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
})()
```

Comment: Did you try running headfully and not closing the browser so you can visually look at the page to confrm that there are no errors in the console and the image is there? That'd be the first thing I'd do to debug. If the image isn't there or there's an error, there's the problem. If the image is there, there's no error and everything looks good, then it's time to think about loading race conditions, which can be debugged with `waitForTimeout`. If the image shows up on a 5-second timeout, then there's probably a loading race condition. You can try to tighten the predicate with `waitForFunction`.

Comment: I've tried all the methods you said however it didn't work , The version I'm using is "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "puppeteer": "^19.4.1"

Comment: Thanks for the response. ["It didn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) doesn't tell me a whole lot or give me much of anything to follow up on, unfortunately. When you tried the methods, what happened exactly?

Comment: When I create a pdf the writing appears, but the image does not , I even used this solution but nothing changed .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751136/puppeteer-does-not-load-images-stored-locally-when-generate-pdf

Comment: I got that from the original question. What I'm trying to ask is whether when you launched with headless: false, did you see any errors in the console or not? If there were, what were they? If there weren't, then did you add a sleep to test for race conditions? You are confirming that there are no errors in the console and adding a 5 second sleep still doesn't make the images show up? No failed requests in the network tab? Then is your HTML valid and the script works in a normal browser without Puppeteer? If all of this is true, I don't know how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you see a CORS error in the console, the link you shared as well as [How to point Puppeteer to local images/fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078896/how-to-point-puppeteer-to-local-images-fonts) are good ones--serve those files on localhost, if you are in fact running on localhost (please confirm that that's your plan--you're not running on a server).

Comment: Yes I have launched my page with header:false , in console no error and no image is showing . I also tried showing the page in the browser without the puppeteer image showing up.. The problem is only in the stage of converting the page HTML to PDF with Puppeteer ... Is there a feature in this version ( "puppeteer": "^19.4.1" )  that must be activated in order for the images to be read from local?

Comment: Hmmm... still not sure how to reproduce but thanks for the details. Did you try running a server and the flags shown in https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1643? Something seems very wrong if the base64 encoding didn't work either.