# Image not being rendered in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have created a handlebars template and compiled it with my custom data. Everything else works fine just the image is not being displayed in the template.

I have done the following:

> Made the images folder static using express

```
app.use(express.static("assets"));
```

> used the image in the template

```
 <img src="sign.png"/>
```

Here is my code where I'm using the template

```
const compile = async function (templateName, data) {
    const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'Template', `${templateName}.hbs`);
    const html = await fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8');
    return hbs.compile(html)(data);
}

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
        const content = await compile('Passes', jsonData);
        await page.setContent(content);
        await page.emulateMediaType('screen');
        await page.pdf({
            path: 'PASSES/' + filenameWE + '.pdf',
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true
        });
        console.log("Done ---- " + filenameWE);
        await browser.close();
```

Again, I have tried the following:

> Made the images folder static using express
> used the image in the template

Comment: Look at the Chrome inspector network tab

Comment: It is not clear to me if/how express.js is being used. It looks to me that your issue is due to the fact that Puppeteer has no path to that image on your file system. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55078896/3397771